# Unit test for a method that detects files that are symbolic links

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I need to write a unit test in Java for a method that detects files that are symbolic links. The test would have to create temporary files that are symbolic links. The trouble is that on Windows 10, and probably other versions of Windows, the unit test would need admin privileges to create a symbolic link. Does anyone have a way to handle special-case issues like this in unit tests?

Comment: Why do you **have** code to detect 'files that are symbolic links'?   Why isn't `Files.isSymbolicLink(Path.of(filename))` all you need? And I suggest you don't need to test whether the Java library does what it says it will do.

Comment: We need more details about what the code does specifically, and which aspects you want to test. Is mocking all API calls that actually perform IO operations an option for you?

Comment: For the sake of precision, I'd call a test that test that code correctly interacts with the platform an Integration Test, not a unit test (although it may be implemented using a Unit Test framework). For such a test, I'd usually set up the test input (the files in this case) through a separate channel (e.g. a build script).

Comment: For testing filesystem stuff, there's [Jimfs](https://www.baeldung.com/jimfs-file-system-mocking) which lets you mock out an entire system. Optimally, unit tests should not touch disk whatsoever; jimfs lets you do that (also speeding things up, disks are relatively slow), and would let you create a symlink without admin privileges (as it's all just a fake filesystem).

Comment: For the more general question, there is https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10, which also explains how to grant the right to create links to other users.

Comment: @ArfurNarf You are right. The code uses `Files.isSymbolicLink()`. The unit test checks to make sure the method is getting called under the correct circumstances.

Comment: @Hulk Thank you for your ideas. A build script sounds like a good idea, but I'm not sure if it's practical in our cross-platform development environment.

Comment: @ rzwitserloot Thank you. I need to check out Jimfs, which sounds like it might be exactly what I need.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Well, Jimfs certainly looked like a good idea. However, one of the methods I need to test is an implementation of `java.io.FileFilter`, which takes a `java.io.File` as its first parameter. Unfortunately, creating a File from a Path using Jimfs is an unsupported operation. In fact, the Javadocs for `Path.toFile()` explicitly states that it only returns a File if the Path was created by the default FileSystem. Otherwise, it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException.` But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz whatever system is distributing your builds to your test environment(s) is usually also capable of creating files. If you want the files to really exist, the either account of this system or the account executing the test will need the required rights. If you prefer mocking, we'll need more info on what concrete problems you are facing. You mentioned some in the comments, but please add this info to the question.

Comment: @Hulk Thank you for your input. I've developed a unit test that creates temporary files, and successfully mocks them on Windows. Fiddling with the system that distributes the build makes the problem bigger. I've managed to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class SymbolicLinkDetectorTest {

    @Test
    public void testDetectSymbolicLink() throws IOException {
        File tempFile = createTempFile();
        if (isSymbolicLinkSupported()) {
            Files.createSymbolicLink(tempFile.toPath(), new File("c:\\temp").toPath());
            assert SymbolicLinkDetector.detectSymbolicLink(tempFile);
        } else {
            assert !SymbolicLinkDetector.detectSymbolicLink(tempFile);
        }
    }

    private File createTempFile() throws IOException {
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".tmp");
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        return tempFile;
    }

    private boolean isSymbolicLinkSupported() {
        return System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is along the lines of what I'm currently trying. But I think the method to test if symbolic links are supported might better be written as `return !System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows");` (I'm developing on a Mac.) `;)`